# Правила перезаписи RewriteRule

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, apache

Здрaвствуйте. Можете объяснить, как работает `RewriteRule` в данном примере? Представим, что есть WordPress с включенным ЧПУ и страницей с адресом `example.com/privet`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Допустим, мы заходим по адресу `example.com/privet`

Вопрос: как для сервера будет выглядеть адрес страницы `example.com/privet` после первого прохода по правилам перезаписи?

Правильно ли я понял, что любой существующий адрес после первого прохода преобразуется в `example.com/index.php`?

Comment: Нет. Всё зависит от настроек пермалинков. При включении ЧПУ index.php  последний кто может включиться в работу. См https://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png

Comment: @SeVlad спасибо за ответ, но это уже происходит после того, как сервер обработал запрос и отправил его дальше. А мне хотелось бы узнать, что происходит до этого момента.

Comment: @SeVlad допустим у нас вот такие настройки ЧПУ `exaple.com/%postname%` - что произойдет в данном случае?

Comment: Пардон. Я выше писал про индексный файл ТЕМЫ. Сейчас в ответе напишу.

Answer (score 1):

> Можете объяснить, как работает RewriteRule в данном примере?

Эти правила означают буквально следующее: если по указанному адресу не обнаружен физический каталог или файл, то запрашивается index.php в корне сайта.
Далее в работу вступают подключаемые файлы и, в соответствии с настройками ЧПУ, роутинг пытается отдать релевантную страницу.

Comment: ещё раз спасибо за ответ. Я, наверное, не могу правильно сформулировать вопрос. Смотрите. Сейчас я говорю только о сервере (до того, как запрос поступит в WordPress). При первой итерации правила перезаписи превратят адрес из `example.com/privet` в `example.com/index.php`, но на первой итерации сервер не отправит эту ссылку `example.com/index.php` дальше в WordPress. Перед этим будет второй раунд поиска совпадений. И если совпадений не будет, то только в этом случае сервер пропустит ссылку дальше.

Comment: @caboke Ну я ж написал - на сервере идет проверка наличия физических каталогов/файлов и ЕСЛИ их нет - только после этого уже передаётся в ВП. И никто адреса не превращает